# Trying To Plot Json Data On World Map Using leafletjs But Data Displayed is Not Accurate

Tags: json, d3.js, leaflet

I Created World Map Using leafletjs And Now Trying To Display Data From https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/meteorite-strike-data.json As Circle My Data Distribution Output Looks Like

[image]

As Of Now Considering Radius As Constant

But It Should Look Like

[image]

As Data Is Distributed Across Map

My Codes Are

```js
// load and display the World
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/meteorite-strike-data.json", function(error, data) {
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [20.0, 5.0],
            minZoom: 2,
            zoom: 2
        });
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" title="OpenStreetMap" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" title="MapQuest" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png" width="16" height="16">',
            subdomains: ['otile1', 'otile2', 'otile3', 'otile4']
        }).addTo(map);
        data.features.forEach(function (data2) {
            var coordinates = ([+data2.properties.reclong, +data2.properties.reclat]);
            var circle = L.circle([coordinates[0],coordinates[1]], 10, {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }).addTo(map);
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forced Layout</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.6.7/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.20/topojson.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--
       <div class="mainContainer text-center">
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>  
    
        -->
   
    <div id="map" style="height: 440px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cannelflow/hs3wL08u/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
var coordinates = ([+data2.properties.reclong, +data2.properties.reclat]);
```

it should have been this

```
var coordinates = ([+data2.properties.reclat, +data2.properties.reclong]);
```

When you create a circle in leaflet the first array element is lat second is lon. [refer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle)

```
L.circle([50.5, 30.5], 200).addTo(map);
```

For latlng object lat comes first then lon [refer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng)

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c4dnLwfu/)

Comment: thanks can you suggest a way so that i can make radius and color dynamic like radius should change according to mass and color should be of scale var color = d3.scale.category20c();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512560/getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-on-leafle